# Fetching HTML input from text and drop down menu in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, text, input, drop-down-menu

I want to provide users two input mechanisms - text entry and drop down menu by using  element. The input value is fetched in javascript. (no php used).

I can make each method work, but not simultaneously.

This is probably fundamental question, but could someone explain how I need to set up event-handlers as well as value for each input to make this work?

```
<form name="myform"  onsubmit="return userInput()">
    <select id="myVal" onchange="userInput()" onsubmit="return userInput()">
        <option>Select a country</option>   
        <option value="All Countries">All Countries </option>
        <option value="Austrailia">Austrailia</option>
        <option value="Korea">Korea </option>
        <option value="Austria">Austria </option>
        <option value="United States of America">United States of America    
        </option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada </option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
    </select>


         <!-- <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Add to list" > -->
        <input type="text" id="myVal" placeholder="Add some text&hellip;">

 </form>

// Javascript code where I fetch user input.

   function userInput(event){
               userinput = document.getElementById("myVal").value
             //  console.log(userinput)
                // console.log(document.getElementById("myVal").value)
            //draw(document.getElementById("myVal").value)
           d3.select('svg').remove();
            main();
            console.log("Main has been called")
            // draw(document.getElementById("myVal").value)
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Your `userInput()` will always return `false`?

Comment: Yes. It looks like for text input, the callback function needs to return false? Frankly, I am not too familiar with handling input with javascript, so I don't understand the dynamics 100% other than the mark-up portion.

Comment: why 2 `onsubmit()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your select element and your text input element have the same ID. Make them unique and make one call for each element in your JS. Also, get rid of the onsubmit event handler attribute in your select element.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just curious; can we attach "submit" event to drop down list? Or, is "onchange" the only event that can be used with drop down list?

Comment: No, only onchange as-well as onclick and some others. You can do everything you need to do with the form's onsubmit event handler. You can use "this" inside of your function to refer to the form element itself.